# numeric value from html being read as a string

Tags: javascript

I've simplified my code here to show that I have a value which is passed in to "mydiv1" which is always a number. I would like to be able to reference this to perform actions depending on whether it's negative or positive, but it must be being seen as a string. Is there any way this value can be got as a number? All topics i've seen such as parseInt() seem to relate to when a variable is specified rather than got from the html.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
      //  var firstDivContent =  "23";
        if (firstDivContent > 0) {
            alert('positive')
        }
        else if (firstDivContent < 0) {
            alert ('negative')
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<div id="mydiv1">23</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"All topics i've seen such as parseInt() seem to relate to when a variable is specified rather than got from the html."* Right. You get it from the HTML and the parse it (using `parseInt` or the unary `+` or `Number` or `parseFloat`...). E.g.: `var firstDivContent = Number(document.getElementById("mydiv1").innerHTML;`

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns the whole element: `<div id="mydiv1">23</div>`. Not just its contents. This will always be `> 0`, if the element exits.

Comment: What you are doing right there is getting the actual div elemtn, not the value inside the the div tags. what you need to do is call the "parseint()" method on  firstDivContent.innerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
        firstDivContent = parseFloat(firstDivContent.innerHTML);
        if (firstDivContent > 0) {
            alert('positive')
        }
        else if (firstDivContent < 0) {
            alert ('negative')
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<div id="mydiv1">23</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `innerHTML` to get the HTML content of a div and then use `parseFloat` to convert the string to a number.

Comment: parseInt would only work for integer, the question deals with numbers, it would probably better to use the Number(myVar) form

Comment: @laurent You are right, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You should add some code for having type safety here. firstDivContent can result in NaN here as well, if #mydiv1 contains crap.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `innerHTML` of your element. Then you can use `parseInt()` or `+yourVar` to convert the string to a number

```js
var firstDivContent = +(document.getElementById('mydiv1').innerHTML);
if (firstDivContent > 0) {
  alert('positive')
} else if (firstDivContent < 0) {
  alert('negative')
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv1">23</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use the "+" operator to make the cast to number more cleanly, in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2L9sj93/10/), you can test it:

```
function myFunction() {
        var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
      //  var firstDivContent =  "23";
        if (firstDivContent > 0) {
            alert('positive')
        }
        else if (firstDivContent < 0) {
            alert ('negative')
        }
    }
```